# How to Fire DropDownClosed Event from a Button

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a WinForms app. My `ComboBox` has `DropDownClosed` event, but I need to fire this event from a `Button`. How can I do this?

Comment: Duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184614/trigger-controls-event-programmatically

Comment: Most of the answers here have function invoke solution and it's probably fine for you but they not answers the question "how to fire event from code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1_DropDownClosed(sender, e);
}

private void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

Comment: If I want to fire DropDownClosed from within form_load, how can I do this?

Comment: @Aidin...In same way. Just call the `comboBox1_DropDownClosed(sender, e);` in your `form_load`. Like this: `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1_DropDownClosed(sender, e);
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look , I believe this is what you are talking about

```
 private void abc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
}

private void xyz_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
   abc_Click(sender, args);
}
```